# How to convert varchar column values into int?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I have a column `toysid` which is of `varchar` datatype in one table. Also another table having same the column `toysid` with `int` datatype  (I know I can modify column for first table but I have to follow some procedure to keep it as `varchar`).

I have written following query to join the table:

```
select study.toysid 
from study 
join concepts on study.toysid = concepts.toysid
```

The query returns error:

> Conversion failed wher converting varchar datatype into int

Hence I have tried below query:

```
select study.toysid 
from study 
join concepts on convert(int, study.toysid) = concepts.toysid
```

I got the same error. How to convert it? I have searched in many websites but I'm unable to get solution. Please anyone help on this.

Comment: It is because there is a data in your `study.toysid` which can't be converted to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit such records which having non-numeric value and then cast with integer like below:

```
select Mystudy.toysid 
from concepts 
     join (Select study.toysid From study WHERe ISNUMERIC(study.toysid)= 1) As MyStudy 
          on convert(int, MyStudy.toysid) = concepts.toysid
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you dont have anything other than numbers in your `toysid` column. I suspect there are characters other than numbers in that column. once you are sure, try the below query..

```
select study.toysid 
from study join concepts 
on cast(study.toysid as int) = concepts.toysid
```

**or**

```
select study.toysid 
from study join concepts 
on cast(study.toysid as varchar(100)) = cast(concepts.toysid as varchar(100))
```

Comment: i have tried these two queries but the same error exist. That column having value like 001, 002, 003

Comment: Try below query to find all values which are not numeric..
SELECT toysid  FROM YOURTABLE WHERE ISNUMERIC(toysid) = 0